# How would I match all "quote blocks" in plaintext e-mail in PHP PCRE?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match all the quotes in the following example e-mail message:

```
> Don't forget to buy eggiweggs on the way home.

I shall not.

> Also remember to brush your shoes.

Will do.

> > > And clean up after the pigs.
> > But I have no pigs.
> Yes, you do. Your kids.

I see what you mean. They sure make a mess.
```

That means I want to match these three strings:

```
> Don't forget to buy eggiweggs on the way home.
```

And:

```
> Also remember to brush your shoes.
```

And:

```
> > > And clean up after the pigs.
> > But I have no pigs.
> Yes, you do. Your kids.
```

I don't understand how I can do this, since if I use the `s` flag to span multiple lines, which is required for this, I cannot refer to `^` and `$` to mean "beginning of line" and "end of line" -- instead, they mean "beginning of string" and "end of string".

So if I do: `#^(> .+?)$#us`, it will match everything after/with the first quote.

And if I do: `#^(> .+?)$#um`, it will match only the first quote's first line and nothing else.

This is frustrating. I really have no idea how to solve it. I've searched online before asking and found zero even remotely relevant pages as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all('~^> .*(?:\R> .*)*~m', $txt, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];
```

*(where `\R` is an alias for several newline sequences)*

---

With `preg_split`:

```
$result = preg_split('~^(?!> ).*\R?~m', $txt, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

that splits the string on each line that doesn't start with `>` .
To trim the newline at the end of each block, you can start this pattern with an optional `\R?` => `~\R?^(?!> ).*\R?~m` or like that `~(?:\R?^(?!> ).*)+\R?~m` to eventually grab several lines at a time.

---

**About `\R`:**
 `\R` is by default an alias for `(?>\r\n|\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85)` (any non-utf8 8bits characters sequences for a newline). In utf8 mode, with the u modifier or starting the pattern with `(*UTF8)(*BSR_UNICODE)`, two other characters oustide of the ASCII range are added to the list: the line separator (U+2028), the paragraph separator (U+2029).

It's handy when you don't know which newline sequence is used in the string but slower than writing the exact newline sequence if you know it. You can restrict `\R` to `(?>\r\n|\n|\r)` with the directive `(*BSR_ANYCRLF)` at the start of the pattern.

Comment: +1. Would be helpful to explain the regex (both the idea behind it and the literal syntax used), and `print_r` the exact output which confirms it does what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to split the string based on the line breaks. maybe this will help you?

```
foreach(explode("\n", $string) as $key=>$val) {
  if(preg_match('/^(>.*)$/', $val, $match))
    echo $match[1] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

output:

```
> Don't forget to buy eggiweggs on the way home.
> Also remember to brush your shoes.
> > > And clean up after the pigs.
> > But I have no pigs.
> Yes, you do. Your kids.
```

edit: i tried something else... but it is not perfect

```
preg_match_all("/(>[^\n]+)/sm", $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => > Don't forget to buy eggiweggs on the way home.
    [1] => > Also remember to brush your shoes.
    [2] => > > > And clean up after the pigs.
    [3] => > > But I have no pigs.
    [4] => > Yes, you do. Your kids.
)
```

Comment: Doesn't this treat every individual line of a "quote block" as a separate match?

Comment: yes, the first example goes line by line.

Comment: I might be extremely tired, but doesn't the second one as well?

Answer (score 0):

## Explicitly match the end of the quote

Rather than attempting to tweak greedy/none-greedy behavior it's easiest to solve regex problems if you can match something unambiguous at the start/end of the match.

When a quoted block continues on multiple lines, the last characters of the line are [newline] + `>`, when a quoted block ends the last characters of the quote are [newline] + [not >] - This logic/pattern allows finding the whole quoted blocks.

From this logic we arrive at:

```
/(> .+?)\n[^>]/s
```

This is:

```
/           # Regex start delimiter
  (         # Start of capturing group
    >       # Literal >
            # Literal space
    .       # Any character, including newlines
    +?      # At least once, none-greedy match
  )         # End of Capturing group
  \n        # Newline
  [^>]      # anything _except_ a literal >
/           # Regex end delimiter
s           # PCRE_DOTALL flag (makes . also match newlines)
```

The use of a none-greedy match here prevents the regex matching the start of the first quote all the way to the end of the last quote.

Choosing between (or combining) PCRE_DOTALL and PCRE_MULTILINE depends on the strategy employed - here the intent is only to modify the behavior of `.`. [More info in the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

If the source text is coming from windows, you may wish to use `\R` (as noted in a different answer).

## Demonstration

```
<?php

$input = <<<STUFF
> Don't forget to buy eggiweggs on the way home.

I shall not.

> Also remember to brush your shoes.

Will do.

> > > And clean up after the pigs.
> > But I have no pigs.
> Yes, you do. Your kids.

I see what you mean. They sure make a mess.
STUFF;

$regex = "/(> .+?)\n[^>]/s";
preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => > Don't forget to buy eggiweggs on the way home.


            [1] => > Also remember to brush your shoes.

            [2] => > > > And clean up after the pigs.
> > But I have no pigs.
> Yes, you do. Your kids.


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => > Don't forget to buy eggiweggs on the way home.
            [1] => > Also remember to brush your shoes.
            [2] => > > > And clean up after the pigs.
> > But I have no pigs.
> Yes, you do. Your kids.
        )

)
```

## Why don't the attempts in the question work?

> So if I do: `#^(> .+?)$#us`

The s modifier only affects `^` and `$`.

This regex is anchored to the start and end of each line (does a none-greedy match, but the `.` will not match a newline anyway) - hence it matches each quoted line individually.

> And if I do: `#^(> .+?)$#um`

The m modifier only affects `.`.

It has no effect on `^` or `$` - so as noted in the question this can at most produce one match.

Flags are not mutually exclusive, and can be used in combination.

Comment: The `u` (lowercase) modifier stands for a combination of `PCRE2_UCP` (that extends character classes like `\w`, `\d` to unicode) and `PCRE2_UTF` (with it the pattern and the subject are read code point by code point instead of byte by byte) . The `U` (uppercase) stands for `PCRE2_UNGREEDY`.

Comment: Whoops. Corrected @CasimiretHippolyte - thanks